# How to use DataAvailableFcn in appdesigner in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I'm struggling with DataAvailableFcn to receive data from Bluetooth Low Energy device in appdesigner.
Due to example: [Work with Device Characteristics and Descriptors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/work-with-device-characteristics-and-descriptors.html)
displayCharacteristicData(src,evt) should have two input arguments - src and evt. It works in script file.
However, I cannot call the hanlder function in appdesigner, where all private functions have input argument (app)
Example:

```
        function results = func(app)
            
        end
```

I've tried

```
function displayCharacteristicData(app,src,evt)
    [data,timestamp] = read(src,'oldest');
    disp(data);
    disp(timestamp);
end
```

and

```
function displayCharacteristicData(src,evt)
    [data,timestamp] = read(src,'oldest');
    disp(data);
    disp(timestamp);
end
```

calling it using

```
c.DataAvailableFcn = @app.displayCharacteristicData
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to specify such callback is below.

```
c.DataAvailableFcn = @(src, event) displayCharacteristicData(app, src, event);
```

and function definition is the following

```
function displayCharacteristicData(~, src, evt)
    [data,timestamp] = read(src,'oldest');
    disp(data);
    disp(timestamp);
end
```